# Not trusting file .hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group dev

Tags: mercurial, permissions, ssh, repository

The repository is owned by user root, and group dev

Another user is running `hg update` on the repository and getting the following messages:

```
Not trusting file /dev/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group dev
Not trusting file .hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group dev
Not trusting file /dev/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group dev
Not trusting file /dev/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group dev
abort: Permission denied: /dev/src/backend/java/com/tt/afr/schedule/service/ScheduleComparator.java
```

In `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`, we have:

```
trusted.users=root
```

In the home directory of user running `hg update`, we have this hgrc file:

```
[trusted]
users = root
groups = dev
```

User is connecting to server using `ssh` and running the commands.

What can we do to fix this?

Comment: You do know that /dev is used for other things, right?

Comment: It's not actually dev, it's our app name, i only changed it in the question. Silly of me to forget that dev is used for other things.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Please read the [help on trust in Mercurial](http://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Trust) and make sure that you've added the trust settings *on the server*. When you connect over SSH, it does not matter who you trust or don't trust locally — it's the `hg` binary that you run on the server (via the SSH tunnel) that needs to trust the config file.

Also note that you need to put

```
[trusted]
users = root
```

in the `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` file on the server. The `section.key = name` syntax we use when talking about configuration settings only work on the command line.

Comment: From the article you linked: Set trusted.users=root in /etc/mercurial/hgrc, and then have your repository's hgrc owned by root.

Comment: Yes, but understand that `foo.bar=baz` is what you use on the command line with `--config`, in a configuration *file* you need to use normal ini-file syntax: `[foo] bar = baz` instead.

Comment: I've just updated the wiki page to use the right syntax for the config file, I hope that helps!

Comment: You're right, that worked. Silly of me to think hgrc files would have different syntaxes(syntice?) at different locations.

Comment: No problem! I can see why the wiki page was confusing, so I fixed the page :-)

Comment: The link does not work! Must be https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Trust or something other.

Comment: I still find this confusing, so I'll note that (contrary to my expectation from reading this answer and the wiki) my case was fixed by making the change in my _local_ `~/.hgrc`.  I was trying a `log -R /path/to/repo`, and getting "not trusting file /eng/apt/repo/apt/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user 1234, group 5678".  When I added `[trusted] users = 1234` to my `~/.hgrc`, the warning went away.

Comment: `chmod g+s -R mydir` to make group name sticky so new files keep group

Answer (score 32):

For everybody else who has added this solution to their /repo/.hg/hgrc and nothing happened, this solution worked for me:
https://j.ee.washington.edu/trac/gmtk/ticket/33

Add in  `/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/trust.rc`

```
[trusted]
groups = yourgroup
users = youruser
```

Essentially, writing permissions to /repo/.hg/hgrc will not work, because the file itself is owned by an untrusted user.

Comment: Your solution is very useful for OpenBSD. There is a special path `/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d`  and file `/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/openbsd-security.rc`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by DustWolf, this works on Ubuntu under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) using a Windows drive letter share mounted using Microsoft's WSL `drvfs` file system driver, i.e., `hg` running locally on a shared drive.

```
not trusting file /mnt/x/repo/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.3.1)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2020 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Create `trust.rc` on the WSL machine:

```shell
sudo touch /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/trust.rc
sudo nano /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/trust.rc
```

Add:

```ini
[trusted]
groups = root
users = root
```

Save `trust.rc` and `hg` should now trust the repo `hgrc` as WSL's `drvfs` driver mounts the share as root:root.

[wsl](/questions/tagged/wsl) [wsl-drvfs](/questions/tagged/wsl-drvfs)

Answer (score 0):

Not your case, but might be worth a hint:

I had this error in a local container that was setup to migrate repos from hg to GitLab. Solved it by just by changing the ownership of the `.hg` directory in the downloaded hg's repository folder to root user/group:

```
chown -R root:root .hg
```

And the message `not trusting file /data/hg-repo/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user 1000, group 1000` was gone.